# How to test a service in Angular with $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have a simple service:

```
.factory('list', function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            var dfd = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function () {
                dfd.resolve(['label1', 'label2']);
            }, 10);

            return dfd.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

and want to test it. So I created:

```
describe('list', function() {

    var list, labels;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($q, _list_) {
       list = _list_;

       spyOn(list, 'get').and.callThrough();

       list.get().then(function(result) {
           labels = result;
       });
    }));

    describe('getting list of labels', function() {

        it('should return list of labels', function() {
            expect(labels).not.toBe(undefined);
            expect(Array.isArray(labels)).toBeTruthy();
        });

     });

});
```

But the problem is, that the callback in then function isn't executed, even though the get method in service returns promise. Am I doing something wrong? I read about callFake method in Jasmine, but to be honest I don't see a point in using it. Could you explain what are some benefits of using it? Btw I have Jasmine 2.0 and latest angular with angular-mocks.

Comment: `beforeEach` takes a function as an argument. If you want it to be async, then the function should accept a callback function. Check this quetion http://stackoverflow.com/q/25598353/1197333

Comment: I don't really understand how it should work. I have now `beforeEach(function(done))`, but when should I call it? Inside `then` (that didn't work) or outside (neither)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple and I forgot about it. Due to the fact I used $timeout I should have called `flush` afterwards.